# Scheduled Executor Service with single thread

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a sample code for Scheduled Executor Service, taken from Oracle's site. It creates a ScheduledExecutorService with core pool size o 1. It does 2 jobs: First it starts a repeated task executed at fixed intervals and then it kills the same task and the service itself after a delay.

```
 ScheduledExecutorService scheduledService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
         //This will keep executing the task at fixed interval
         ScheduledFuture<?> futureTask = scheduledService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RepeatedTask(), initialDelay, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         //A future task is returned which can be used to cancel the execution after sometime
         //Here we will cancel our repeated task after 100 seconds
         scheduledService.schedule(new TaskStopper(futureTask, scheduledService), 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The repeated task code:

```
public class RepeatedTask implements Runnable{
    int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count + ". Beep");
    }

}
```

The stop task

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        mFutureTask.cancel(true);
        System.out.println("Task stopped");
        mExecutorService.shutdownNow();
        boolean shutDown = mExecutorService.isShutdown();
        if(shutDown) {
            System.out.println("Executor shutdown");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Executor not shutdown");
        }
    }
```

I want to understand, how does it work with a single thread in the thread pool.
Since our executor service performs two tasks and starts them both almost at the same time,
shouldn't we have 2 threads i.e. a ScheduledExecutorService with core pool size of 2.

It works fine though. I just want to understand why it works fine with a single thread.

Comment: Aren't the 2 tasks happening sequentially?

Comment: Both tasks are executed via the Scheduled Executor service which has core pool size of 1. On the same service instance first we call scheduleAtFixedRate and then schedule with a delay. First task  starts after 10 seconds and keeps repeating after 10 seconds each. Second task is supposed to execute after 100 seconds delay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any thread pool (including ScheduledThreadPool), number of threads can be less than number of tasks. Thread pools internally have a queue of tasks, in which a task will have to wait if no thread is available to execute the task.

In your example, at t=100 seconds, two tasks need to be executed. Since only one thread is available, it executes the first task (while second one waits in the queue). Once the first task is complete, the thread picks the second task from the queue and completes it.

You could print out the thread id in both the tasks and can verify that they are indeed being processed by the same thread.

Edit:
So basically the task scheduled at fixed interval is executed multiple times with fixed intervals in between. During these intervals, our single thread in the pool is idle and is able to pick other tasks for execution. That's how a single thread executes both the tasks.

Comment: Indeed, there can be n number of submitted tasks and the threads in the pool, execute them one by one. In my case, the first task is an infinite loop, so it won't be completed when the second task is picked for execution. I was thinking that probably the single existing thread employs time slicing to execute submitted tasks and that's how second task gets an opportunity to be executed.

Comment: First task by itself is not infinite, it is a simple increment and print. Multiple prints are a result of multiple executes of the task. The number of executions of the first however are infinite (and is terminated as a result of second task).

Comment: Yes of course. My bad. It's not an infinite loop. So I guess we say that during the multiple executions of task1 which has fixed intervals in between, task 2 is picked by the Thread, while task1 execution is in pause state.

Comment: If you agree with the above discussion, can you add your comment data in the answer, so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: @Ankit I don't agree with your use of "pause" status. Task 1 is scheduled at fix rate, so after every 10 second - the task is submitted and executed. It is never paused (it may spend some time waiting in queue though if thread is busy).

Comment: That being said, I am happy to add any extra information that you think should be part of the answer.

Comment: By pause, I meant the gap in successive executions of the task. Indeed in one round of execution, there is no pause. I just wanted to ensure that task2 gets a chance to execute only when task1 was not getting executed and hence the idle thread picks it up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220851/discussion-between-rishabh-sharma-and-ankit).